# buggy mission control shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, mission-control

I am having an issue where somehow lion decided that the F1 shortcut should be mapped to opening mission control on my 2011 mbp.

This is a problem because I had F1 mapped to desktop 4 (don't ask) and F5 mapped to mission control.  F5 still worked correctly and even after attempting to revert to defaults the F1 keyboard shortcut is still incorrectly mapped.

Has anyone been having similar issues or do they know how to totally reset keyboard shortcuts at the operating system level?

This is obviously really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try double-clicking on the actual keyboard short cut for that function in System Preferences/Keyboard/Keyboard Shortcuts?  You can change the key combo at will.  Of course there is no guarantee they will take, just as your "Restore Defaults" did not take.

I use Spark, a free app that lets me map anything I want, and overrides the OS settings.  If there is a con flit (which shows as the yellow triangle/traffic cone), I change the OS conflict to some unused combo.

I complained to Apple that I could not change those keyboard shortcuts to "Open app X".  The response was that I should not try to do that, as the existing system was working as designed.

This is not a built-in cure using the native OS options, but it works.